# Implement Google drive v3 api in Angularjs project

Tags: angularjs, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am implementing Google drive v3 api in AngularJS version 1 project. I have gone through the docs and the related stuffs but still unable to implement it successfully. Sometime I get the error "Daily unauthorized limit exceeded" and sometime "File not found" against the query gapi.client.drive.files.list.
Here is my js code:enter code here

```
function start() {
                gapi.client.init({
                    'apiKey': 'AIzaSyBqVx6XgBXjvbLZNP-aX8gBqi8pXZZhOxw',
                    'discoveryDocs': ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest'],
                }).then(function (res) {
                    console.log(res);
                    gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                        'pageSize': 10,
                        'q': "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false",
                        'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
                    }).then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        } else {
                            console.log('No files found.');
                        }
                    }, function (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    });
                })
            };

            gapi.load('client', start);
```

Comment: you are not using oauth. likely your files are public. make them private and get the oauth2 flow. show us the code for the oauth2 flow, and issues with it. google more. its unrelated to agular.

Answer (score 0):

"Daily unauthorized limit exceeded" means you've sent a Drive request without an Access Token. That suggests that somehow you've bypassed the auth dialogue, or it failed.

Comment: Yeah i am unable to get access token. I have found nothing for getting access token in AngularJS

Comment: There is plenty of documentation on how to use gapi to get an access token. Start with https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication